# Como cambio el color por defecto azul de un JMenu al dar clic?

Tags: java, mouselistener

Quisiera cambiar el color azul por defecto que aparece al dar clic encima, probé ponerle un `MouseListener` asi:

```
//menu del MenuBar
Game = new JMenu("Game");
Game.setOpaque(true);
Game.setForeground(new Color(27, 100, 20));
Game.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
Game.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        if(!Game.isSelected()){
            Game.setBackground(new Color(30, 180, 30));
            Game.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        }
    }
    
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        if(!Game.isSelected()){
            Game.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            Game.setForeground(new Color(30, 137, 30));
        }
    }
    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if(Game.isSelected()){
            Game.setBackground(new Color(30, 137, 30));
            Game.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        } else {
            Game.setBackground(new Color(30, 180, 30));
            Game.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        }
    }
});
```

y funciona el método `mouseEntered()` y el `mouseExited()`, pero cuando el menú esta seleccionado no cambia el color, no se renderizar y busque en google a ver como podría hacerlo y puse `Game.setUI(new BasicButtomUI());` pero al hacerlo me cambia el tamaño texto, me cambia todo, me podrian dar una solucion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay mas de 2 formas, pero podes usar UIManager para cambiar propiedades de como el LookAndFeel muestra los componentes, en este caso cambiar los colores de Metal, creo que es la forma mas fácil.

Deberías crear un método `loadLookAndFeel()` para cargar el LAF modificado, a este se le llama antes de abrir la interfaz gráfica como muestro en el método `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        loadLookAndFeel();
        View view = new View(); // Despliega la interfaz
    });
}

private static void loadLookAndFeel() {
    try {
        //UIManager.put("Menu.background", Color.WHITE);
        UIManager.put("Menu.foreground", new Color(27, 100, 20));
        
        UIManager.put("Menu.selectionBackground", new Color(30, 180, 30));
        UIManager.put("Menu.selectionForeground", Color.WHITE);
        
        UIManager.put("MenuItem.background", Color.decode("#C8FFC8"));
        UIManager.put("MenuItem.selectionBackground", Color.decode("#95FF95"));
        UIManager.put("MenuItem.selectionForeground", Color.BLACK);
        
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MetalLookAndFeel());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se usa mucho cuando quieres cambiar el estilo de todos los componentes de la interfaz sin tener que ir uno por uno, osea que si modificas las propiedades de "Button", todos los botones que halla en la interfaz cambiaran por ese estilo.

Si quieres ver todas las propiedades de los componentes de los diferentes LAF que tiene Swing usa https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/

Comment: Deja lo pruebo y te digo que tal

Comment: Holas me funciono de maravilla, aparte note que pusiste hasta el nombre de las variables que tenia y como lo quería, por la publicación anterior que hice, de hecho por el comentario que me hiciste fue que puse un `JMenuBar` y no un `JList`

Comment: Muchas gracias por siempre brindarme tu ayuda :D

Comment: Y con el ManagerUI puedo cambiar lo de pasar el mouse por arriba?

Comment: Me alegro de que te halla servido! A que te refieres con lo del mouse? Tal como se muestra en la imagen se pueden cambiar todos los colores incluso si el mouse esta sobre el Item o en el mismo Menu.

Comment: Así como en los ítems al pasar el mouse por arriba cambia el color a verde, sin necesidad de cliquearlo, eso también se puede hacer con el menú?, el cambia de color al cliquearlo justo como quiero, pero también se puede hacer que cambie de color al pasar el mouse por arriba sin cliquearlo?

Comment: La diferencia es que el Item si esta seleccionado y puedes verlo en las propiedades que pase en el método. Poder se puede, pero no con UIManager ya que Metal te proporciona algunas propiedades para cambiar y justo para el "Menu" no esta, funciona con el Item por estar teóricamente seleccionado pero puedes solucionarlo agregando el mismo código que tienes en la pregunta, solo que quitando el del Pressed y para evitar estar escribiendo los colores 2 veces usa en el evento ``menu.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Menu.selectionBackground"))`` eso le da al menú el color que esta en la propiedad.

Comment: Perdona me podrias decir donde añado `menu.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Menu.selectionBackground"))` lo añadí en el `mouseEntered()` y el `mouseExited()` pero solo cambia el texto a blanco 

Comment: Es probable que tu menú tenga setOpaque en false debes cambiarlo a true

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132504/discussion-between-juan-alberto-and-jframe).

Comment: Si era cierto, ahora si funciona como debería, muchas, muchas, muchas gracias :D